# can't redirecting after clicking submit button

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to upload a edited csv file, but after submission it do not redirect
with valid message. Actually if any error in the edited csv file it should give the error msg, otherwise success msg.

I want to upload the mark sheet of a particular subject, if the entered mark is not in numeric or it is exceeding the maximum mark valid messages will be displayed and redirect back to my view page.

```
   function import_academic_excel()
 {    
    $optional_index = 0;    
    if ($this->input->post('submit'))
    {     
        $config['upload_path'] = './application/temp_upload/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv'; 
        $this->load->library('upload', $config); 
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
        {  
            $data = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_excel','Choose a .csv file to upload.'); 
            redirect(base_url().'import_evaluation_sheet');  
        }
        else
        {    

          $count_numeric = 0;
            $count_maximum = 0; 

            foreach($result as $field)
            {    
                if($standard == 11 || $standard == 12)
                {  
                   if($evaluation_name == 'ta1' || $evaluation_name == 'ta2' || $evaluation_name == 'ta3')
                        {  

    if($subject_name == 'physics' || $subject_name == 'chemistry' || $subject_name == 'computer_science')   
                            {
                                $theory_name=$subject_name.'_theory';  
                                $practical_name=$subject_name.'_practical';  
                                if($field[$theory_name] == '' )
                                {
                                    $field[$theory_name]=  0; 
                                } 
                                if($field[$practical_name] == '' )
                                {
                                    $field[$practical_name]=  0; 
                                } 
                                if($field[$theory_name] != 'ab') 
                                {
                                    if(!is_numeric($field[$theory_name]))
                                    {   
                                        $count_numeric = $count_numeric + 1;    
                                    }
                                    if($field[$theory_name] > $theory_mark)
                                    {
                                        $count_maximum = $count_maximum + 1;  
                                    }  
                                }
          }
        }
     }
   } 
  }
       if($count_numeric > 0)
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_excel','Please check the marks entered in the file, some marks are not numeric.'); 
            redirect(base_url().'import_evaluation_sheet');   
        }         
        if($count_maximum > 0)
        {     
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_excel','Please check the marks entered in the file, some marks exceeds the maximum marks.');  
            redirect(base_url().'import_evaluation_sheet');   
        }
                   $update_result= $this->data->update_chapter($result,$subject_name,$evaluation_name,$optional_index,$standard,$tool_id);                    
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_excel_success','Updated data successfully'); 
        redirect(base_url().'import_evaluation_sheet');  
    }
   }
```

The loops are working, but it can't enter to the last two if loops.
If I am entering valid csv file it will reflect in the data, but success msg can't displayed.

Comment: Where have you written message for success?

Comment: On your redirected page have you printed your flashdata

Comment: `if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
        {  
            $data = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_excel','Choose a .csv file to upload.'); 
              redirect(base_url().'import_evaluation_sheet');  
           }`

Comment: the above code works correctly. that is at that time it redirects

Comment: You have to `echo $this->session->flashdata('msg_excel_success');` in `import_evaluation_sheet` method

Comment: after clicking the upload button it redirects to a blank page

Comment: might be due to some error